# Django Rest Framework - Why is serializer.data giving me an empty result set but printing the serializer shows me the data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created a view to search posts based on their body text. I added a breakpoint to the view and I tested it with mutliple search terms and it works. The problem I have is when I do a print(serializer) in the console then I see the data of all the posts it found. But doing a print(serializer.data) gives me body:null in the data object in the front end console and an empty dictionary in the back end console.

I am using PostgreSQL

Why am I getting body: null?

Here is the response in the console for print(serializer):

```
SearchSerializer(<QuerySet [<Post: This is a post>, <Post: This is another post>, <Post: Post THREE>, <Post: Post ONE>, <Post: Post ONE by the user>, <Post: Post TWO by the user>]>):
    body = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, label='Content', max_length=5000, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
```

Here is the view:

```
class SearchPosts(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]    

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        term = request.data.get("term")
        posts = Post.objects.filter(body__search=term)
        serializer = SearchSerializer(posts)
        breakpoint()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class SearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'body'
        ]
```

Here is the post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    body = models.TextField("content", blank=True, null=True, max_length=5000)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=["category", "created_at"])
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "post"
        verbose_name_plural = "posts"
        db_table = "posts"
        ordering = ["created_at"]
        get_latest_by = "created_at"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:30]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug
```

How am I then supposed to get the data in the front end?

UPDATE

If in the view the request object looks like this:

```
<rest_framework.request.Request: GET '/api/v1/posts/search/?term=looking'>
```

Then how do I get the term? ('looking' at the moment)

Because request.data gives me None

kwargs is an empty dictionary

So I changed the view and now it makes even less sense:

```
class SearchPosts(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]    

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        term = request.GET.get("term")
        posts = Post.objects.all().filter(body__search=term)
        breakpoint()
        serializer = SearchSerializer(posts)
        
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Now I get an empty result if I do a print(posts). The term is correct I checked that so why is body__search not working anymore?

Changed it to a ListAPIView and I still get an empty data array in the response:

```
# GENERIC VIEW TO GET POSTS FOUND BASED ON A SEARCH TERM
class SearchPosts(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]    
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        term = self.request.GET.get("term")
        return Post.objects.filter(body__search=term)
```

If I remove the filter then all the posts data is in the response so why is body__search not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
  def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_objects = Model.objects.all()
        serializer = YourSerializer(all_objects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

you missed to forgot get function
please refer to the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Comment: Not using get. The request is a post request and I am after the response

Comment: no if you want to see list of result then you should have to write get method otherwise it will be post request or you will not see any result

Comment: there is another way if you want create or delete or list item or update any particular item then you have to use modelViewset for less code

Comment: Changed it to get and still data is an empty array

Comment: dont change it just add get method with post as well

Answer (score 0):

You probably got `AttributeError` while trying to get `serializer.data`. You sent `Queryset` object to the serializer not single instance of `Post` model. If you want to serialize multiple objects just pass [`many`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) parameter as `True`. From docs;

> To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object instance, you should pass the many=True flag when instantiating the serializer.

So, change your usage like;

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(body__search=term)
serializer = SearchSerializer(posts, many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try def get_serializer_class
because in def post - serializer doesn't mean anything

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).